# Adding a two new phases to an Xcode framework project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nskeyedarchiver

I am building [a project on Github](https://github.com/martin-cowie/macaroni) written in Objective-C. It resolves MAC addresses down to manufacturer details. The lookup table is currently stored as text file `manuf.txt` (from the Wireshark project), which is parsed at run-time, which is costly. I would prefer to compile this down to archived objects at build-time, and load that instead.

I would like to amend the build phases such that I:

1. Build a simple compiler
2. Run the compiler, parsing `manuf.txt` and outputting archived objects
3. Build the framework
4. Copy the archived objects into the framwork

I am looking for wisdom on how to achieve steps 1 and 2 using Xcode v7.3 as Xcode provides only a `Copy Files` phase or a `Run Script` phase. An example of other projects achieving similar goals would be inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you are asking is possible, but tricky. The reason is that you will need to write a bunch of class files and then dynamically add them to the project.

Firstly you will need to employ a run script phase to run various tools from the command line to parse your file and generate a number of class files from it. I would suggest looking into various templating engines. For example [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) uses moustache templates to generate API documentation files. You could use the same technique to generate header and implementation files.

Next, rather than generating archived objects an trying to import into a framework. I think you may be better off generating raw source code, adding it to a project and compiling into a framework. Probably simpler in the long run.

To automatically include the generated code I would look into (which means I haven't actually tried this :-) adding a folder reference to the project rather than an Xcode group. Folder references are an option in the 'Add files to  ...' dialog.

Folder references refer to a directory and automatically add the entire contents of that directory to a project. So you can use one to point to the directory where you have generated the source code. This is a much better option than trying to manipulate the project or injecting things into an established framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to parse the file at runtime. After launch you can look for an already existing output, otherwise parse it one time.

However, I have to do something similar at Objective-Cloud. I simply added a run script build phase and put the compiler call into it.